# C# read file on a shared disk

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to read a file which is on a shared disk and I have the error: "The password for this account has expired." I don't know why.
Visual Studio 2019 is launched as admin, I have access to the file location from my PC, the password of the account I use to do it is still ok.
Do I forget something? Do I need a specific setting in Visual or in the startup of the project?

The code in C# to read the file is as follows:

```cs
var stream = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Settings.Folder, fileName));
// Settings.Folder is like "\\\\server-dev\\folder\\subfolder"
// fileName is like "stats_20240603121900.xlsx"
```

The project is a website in .NET5.0

Comment: What account(s) do you use here. Presumably not a domain account?

Comment: To access to the disk from my PC I use a generic admin account (which is registered in the windows Credential Manager). And I'm connected with my company account for the PC session, Visual is launched with a nominative admin account provided by my company.
What do you mean by domain account?

Comment: Edit: the domains of the accounts are differents.

Windows session + nominative admin account: same domain.
Generic admin account to access the shared disk: another domain.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly providing credentials to connect shared folder? [WindowsIdentity Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=net-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1)

Comment: It doesn't work either, I get the error 1326, which is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was executing Visual Studio as administrator. I tried in normal mode it works so I imagine that's what was causing the problem.